# SQL - sort alphabetically for strings within a column

Tags: postgresql

I am working with postgresql and I have a table like this:

```
Group | Name
======================================
1     | Mary
2     | Barry,Ann,Peter
3     | Max,Chris
4     | Richard,Mary,Peter,Oliver
```

The table is an example, you can consider there will be more than 10,000 different names, the max number of names in one group is 4.

I want to sort the name within each group alphabetically so the result would be like this:

```
Group | Name
======================================
1     | Mary
2     | Ann,Barry,Peter
3     | Chris,Max
4     | Mary,Peter,Oliver,Richard
```

Thanks

Comment: Normalize your data so you're not storing multiple values in a single column, and you can do this with a simple ORDER BY. If you choose to store data in a comma-separated list, expect to have to work extra hard every time you want to use it. The proper way would be to have `2 Barry`, `2 Ann`,  `2 Peter` in three separate rows, which would make the query `ORDER BY Group, Name`.

Comment: What is the type of `name`, `text` or `text[]`?

Comment: @kennytm the type of name is text

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t.Group, string_agg(n.names, ',' ORDER BY n.names) AS Name
FROM my_table t,
     regexp_split_to_table(t.Name, ',', 'g') n(names)
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

Comment: Its giving error ERROR: regexp_split does not support the global option SQL state: 22023